# Check if a button Is clicked then do something

Tags: javascript

I have a form with tabs which include buttons. Before the user clicks next, I want to check if at least one or all the buttons have been clicked, if clicked, the next tab shows up. If not, an alert pops up!

```
<button class="btns rem" id="mon">morning</button>
<button class="btns rem" id="oo" >afternoon</button>
<button class="btns rem" id="pp" >night</button>
<button class="btns" id="day" >Next</button>

 <script type="text/javascript" >
    document.getElementById("day").onclick = 
     function(event) {
    var btn= 
      document.getElementsByClassName("btns") ;
        for(x=0; x<btn.length; x++){
    if(btn[x].click == true){
        prompt("open Next page?");
              } 
        else {
       alert("please click at least one button");
    } 
   } 

 </script>
```

Comment: Why are you using buttons instead of checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

**If you like just try it.**

```
<button class="btns rem" id="mon">morning</button>
<button class="btns rem" id="oo" >afternoon</button>
<button class="btns rem" id="pp" >night</button>
<button class="btns" id="day" >Next</button>

<script type="text/javascript" >
   var clickedData = "";
   function setClicked(data){
       clickedData = data;
   }
   var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btns");
    for(x = 0 ; x < btn.length; x++){
        if(btn[x].id !=="day"){
           const val = btn[x].innerHTML;
           btn[x].onclick = function(){ setClicked(val); } 
        }
     } 
   document.getElementById("day").onclick = 
     function(event) {
        if (clickedData !== ""){
           prompt("open Next page?");
        }else{
           alert("please click at least one button");
        }
     }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way of doing it is to use `checkboxes` since you `want to check if at least one or all the buttons have been clicked`. Then attach the `onchange` event.

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("radio-btn") ;
var len = btns.length;
var isSelected = false;
while(len--) {
  btns[len].onchange = function() {
    isSelected = this.checked ? true : false;
  };
} 
document.getElementById("day").onclick = function() {
  if(isSelected) {
    alert("open Next page?");
  }
  else {
    alert("please click at least one button");
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="time" class="radio-btn rem"> Morning<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="time" class="radio-btn rem"> Afternoon<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="time" class="radio-btn rem"> Evening<br>
  <button class="btns" id="day" >Next</button>
</form>
```